# Replace Markup Styles list with custom list

Tags: branding, markup

Is there a way to do this?

I have been unsuccessful in replacing/editing the Markup Styles for rich html text areas with my own list, and am wondering if its possible to do this at all. From what I understand, the styles that control these are in the oob css file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible options, depending on what you are attempting to do and what you have available to you.  You could take nearly [full control](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/b98e2c80-bca0-48c6-ae4a-ac7670cbf300) or you could go the more common route and merely [add your own styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551040.aspx) to the pick list.  The latter approach is usually done by specifying a custom CSS file for the site and including the '.ms-rteCustom-ZZZZZ' styles in that.

Comment: The full control direction was what i was aiming for. Not my choice mind you, but its exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!